# qmake -project: add new file extensions

Tags: file, project, qt-creator, qmake

I'm using QTCreator as a *code editor* for my C++ project, not using the real features of the qmake compilation process.

My project has several subdirectories, in all of which I ran `qmake -project` to create a duummy *.pro* file that simply lists the source and header files in the directory.

In my root folder, I simply created a "main.pro" file that includes all these "subdir/subdir.pro" files.

So it looks like this:

```
./
main.pro
subdir1/
   /include
   /src
   subdir1.pro
subdir2/
   /include
   /src
   subdir2.pro
```

Now my problem is, I use some files that have a special file extension (say, `.ccp`), which are actually some C code but are used in a different step of my compilation process.

They are naturally ignored by the `qmake -project` command and do not appear in my project.

I read [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmake-environment-reference.html#extensions) that I could use the qmake setting `QMAKE_EXT_CPP` to tell it to gather my files as a C-code file, but it doesn't seem to be working.

If I run `qmake -query QMAKE_EXT_CPP`, I get `.cpp::.c::.ccp` (which I set right before), but when running a new qmake, it doesn't take my `.ccp` files in account.

So, three questions:

- Is it possible to make *qmake* take some special extensions as a C++ file, when building the `.pro` file?
- If yes, is it correct to use the QMAKE_EXT_CPP setting?
- If yes, what should be the syntax of the QMAKE_EXT_CPP setting? (mine inspired by [this forum post](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/23839-Qmake-Extra-Targets?p=115625#post115625), but it might be bogus).

Comment: What build system do you use and what platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change QMAKE_EXT_CPP with -project option. The list of cpp extensions used at this stage is hardcoded into qmake. However after initial creation of .pro file you can edit it to extend with support for other extensions:

in test.pro

```
QMAKE_EXT_CPP += .ccp
SOURCES += test.ccp
```

You have to add new files manually.

Comment: Yep, that's what I do right now, but I'd like the -project option to list this automatically :)
My machine runs with Linux 64, and I use a set of Makefiles to compile my project.